# Why webpack cache stucks?

Tags: webpack, caching, build

I want to use caching in webpack production mode, so rebuild will work faster if nothing was changed. And that kind of worked, it reduced webpack run time from 20 seconds to 5 seconds, just to scale. But when i run for 3rd time it stucks for long time - it takes like 1+ minutes.. I ve got 18 cores cpu and m2 ssd with 3gbps write/read speeds, i dont understand what it can do for a minute?

so why 1st run is 20 seconds, second run is 5 seconds and 3rd run is 1 minute!?

i've added following to webpack config:

```
cache: {
      type: 'filesystem',
      compression: false,
      profile: false,
},
```

I am running it with --profile --progress. And when it stucks output shows nothing about what it does for such long time:

```
webpack 5.52.1 compiled with 140 warnings in 3545 ms
Done in 61.30s.

real    1m1,450s
user    0m8,768s
sys     0m0,751s
```

And during that period its like 0% cpu 0% io, seems like its doing nothing.. what could be problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem occured in webpack 5.52, but is fixed in 5.56, not stucking anymore at all